# Web API's (servlets) not automatically mapped by Spring Boot when package is a WAR

Tags: maven, spring-boot

This is somewhat complex so I'll try and explain it step by step.

I've built a Maven/Spring web framework which in theory can be used by any other project. The pom.xml package is of type JAR. This essentially has two web filters in it and some basic authentication code which maps to '/auth/basic' (POST) and accepts a 'username' and 'password' JSON document.

I can successfully build this project using Maven and I can even 'spring-boot:run' it whereby my '/auth/basic' automagically gets mapped. Using CURL, I can query my web API from the command line. Everything works like a charm.

My second Maven/Spring project is another JAR. But this one has specific 'domain' web API's and code. You can create, add and remove users. This too compiles well and when executed via 'spring-boot:run' I can successfully query my web API's with CURL from command line. Users get created, removed, etc.

My main problem is the next part. I would like to have a third project, but this time, it is intended to be a WAR package. The two JARS above are listed as dependencies for this project. They successfully get packaged into my WAR file. The purpose of this project is to have all the html, css, javascript and images files as part of this project. I don't want any Java code in here (other than the Spring Boot main class).

When I launch it with 'spring-boot:run' it successfully boots and I can view my web pages from a browser. I can navigate (using Angular) successfully. My main issue is when any of the above web API's (ie: '/auth/basic' or the '/user/*') are called from JavaScript, I get an HTTP 405. This is quite obvious because no web API's are automagically mapped like when I Spring Boot the two other JARs.

My questions is why is this? Why is it smart enough to automagically find all my controllers and map them when it's a JAR but when it's a WAR, it does not do the same thing?

I would really hate to have to manually add my servlet/filters into the 'web.xml' file. Is there another way around this? A Spring "automagic" way?

Comment: because you are including 2 spring boot jars into a war. Spring Boot jars aren't intended to be used as dependencies but rather standalone. If you want them to be included as dependencies into another project you either need a non spring boot based jar by either removing spring boot out of the picture or let spring boot build 2 artifacts.

Comment: @M.Deinum, that is my end-goal to export everything into a WAR and run it in a standalone Tomcat server. But I'm still not sure how the mapping would get done? From my understanding, Spring has a single Servlet which dispatches to the RestController annotations it automagically finds and which are mapped to the RequestMapping("/domain") annotations. Any ideas you can throw at me? Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Note that the closest thing I have found is this section of literature [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server), which briefly says what to do but does not explain how a standalone Tomcat server would automagically map all of my 'RequestMapping("/sample")' annotations? And note that once again, like every example, the controller is within the package and NOT within a separate JAR file like in my case.

Comment: Where the controller or component is doesn't matter. The issue here, as stated in my first comment, is that you are including 2 spring boot based applications as jar as dependency. That is never going to work due to the structure of those jar files. As mentioned you need package NON spring boot app jars in your application. Everything is then on the class path and mapping (if the packages are scanned!) will be done'.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I apologize if I sound a little skeptic, but I just can't see how Spring could be considered professional and "commercial grade" with such limitations. I'm completely baffled by this. But it would explain why I can't seem to find any literature on the subject. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What limitation? It is a limitation imposed by the structure of the Spring Boot jar (because it is executable). Next to that including 2 massive spring boot application in another spring boot application would mean you would be including dependencies 3 times. Not something you want. Also don't confuse Spring with Spring Boot. It is also documented in the reference guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)...